# Expand list (array) in dart with separator

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm searching for a way to expand a list with a seperator between each list.

Example (add 0 between sublists):

what I have is this:

```
List<List<int>> list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
```

what I want:

```
List<int> newList = [1,2,3,0,4,5,6,0,7,8,9]
```

`list.expand((element) => element)`   can combine the sublist to this: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

but the separator iss missing :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand like this with adding separator item.

```
list.expand((element)=>[...element,0])
```

UPDATE

```
 list.reduce((a,b)=>[...a,0,...b])
```

Comment: but there is one 0 to much at the end :-/

Comment: Oh sorry, could you look updated answer?

Comment: A thing to note here, is that you are ending up recreating `List` objects for each element. It might not matter but should just be noted in case people are going to use this to handle large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to make an extension to `Iterable` like `expandWithSeparator` with support for a separator value:

```
void main() {
  List<List<int>> list = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ];

  print(list.expandWithSeparator((element) => element, 0).toList());
  // [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9]
}

extension<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Iterable<T> expandWithSeparator<T>(
    Iterable<T> Function(E element) toElements,
    T separator,
  ) sync* {
    bool first = true;

    for (final element in this) {
      if (first) {
        first = false;
      } else {
        yield separator;
      }
      yield* toElements(element);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<int>> list = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ];
list.fold([], (total, item) => [...total, if (total.isNotEmpty) 0, ...item]);
```